# Building from the command-line requires a??Business??license

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm new to xamarin and IOS Programming . 
 I have visual Studio 2013 and xcode 6 and xamarin ios 8.6 on my mac and Xamarin.VisualStudio_3.9.236 for my VS 2013 .

I made a new ios project from VS 2013 and just try to run it and I select ios 8.1 for stimulating. But I tried to run and stimulate the app But I keep getting this error "Building from Visual Studio Building from the command-line requires a??Business??license" . What should I do ?What's the problem ?

Comment: Visual Studio support requires a Xamarin Business license.

Comment: @Jason But I already have Business license. I guess that's not the problem

Comment: things to try:  1. restart VS  2. from VS Xamarin menu, log into your account and verify that it shows your license  3. reinstall Xamarin VS

Comment: @Jason , My mistake , I checked my license and it's enterprise . Do you think I need business license?

Comment: No, Enterprise is higher than Business and has the same features.

Comment: @hamid If you visit your Xamarin account page you should see a support email, contact Xamarin they should be able to help you. While on that I would try to repair my Xamarin installation from the windows control panel